# How do I fix the error: "Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints"

Tags: sqlite, uipath

When I set up my SQLite DB and try to get UIPath to read it, I get this error: "Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints"

What can I do to get UIPath to read this?

Comment: What happens when you query this without UiPath?

Comment: Hi Kwoxer, this is an issue with UIPath.  If you create the table and the field is "text" instead of "String" it will work fine if you query within SQLite or use another programming language.  This is an issue with UIPath only.  While you can't fix it in UIPath, you have to tailor the DB if you want it to work with UIPath.  I've also seen this with MaxInt fields.  Unfortunately, there are many things that could cause this error in UIPath but it boils down to how the DB is set up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIPath may produce this error when you try to run a query
“Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints”

The query may work in the command line of the database but not in UIPath but this is deceptive as this is **NOT a UIPath** issue.  It is an issue with the database table itself.  The table elements must be a type that UIPath can use.

For instance, one of the issues documented:
SQLite will allow you to create the database table like this
   create table clients (name text null, email text null, goodstanding text null);
While this is allowable in the database and it will work, UIPath will not be able to read these rows.  Instead, create the table like this:
   create table clients (name string null, email string null, goodstanding string null);

UIPath will not know how to handle a variable type “text”

Once you make the table of type string (or other accepted varialbes int, etc) you will be able to use this in UIPath

Comment: This could happen with MS SQL as well, with nvarchar column type. CAST as varchar helps